# DialogFlow API webhook

Tags: node.js, chatbot

This is my fulfilment code. I want to just display the value matched with finance or anything and send it to dialogflow but whenever I'm running this code all I'm getting is this response "I'm sorry, I don't know this".

```
'use strict';

var https = require('https');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const action = request.body.queryResult.action;
    //const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    if (action != 'input.getfunc1') {
        response.send(buildChatResponse("I'm sorry, I don't know this"));
        return;
    }
    const parameters = request.body.queryResult.parameters;
    var c = parameters.commitee;

    getfunc1(c, response);
});

function func1(c, CloudFnResponse) {
    var e = {
        'corporate strategy & implementation':
            'CSI is a dynamic committee that is the on-ground army of Aaruush. Responsible for internal and external publicity, strategizing work-plans and executing them.',
        'operations & resource management':
            'Operations & Resource Management is a committee which deals with all the resources required for the team, permissions required for proper work flow of Aaruush team. ',
        finance:
            'The Finance Committee examines the accounts, scrutinizes the proposals for expenditures and submits the annual budget for the Aaruush. No expenditure in the budget is incurred without the prior approval of the Finance Committee',
    };
    var g = e[c.toLowerCase()];
    var chat = g;
    CloudFnResponse.send(buildChatResponse(chat));
}

function buildChatResponse(chat) {
    return JSON.stringify({ fulfillmentText: chat });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not a debugging site, thus please could you be more specific. You should investigate by yoursefl the problem, and if it last, provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please show the intents that you have created. Also, what input is resulting in "I'm sorry, I don't know this"?